# SQL INSERT command just does nothing

Tags: python, sql, insert, mariadb

I have a Raspberry Pi set up with Python 3 and MariaDB on it and if I try to execute an insert command from within a Python script, nothing happens: no error message, but no changes in the database either.

If I use the same command in phpmyadmin though, it works just fine.

The connection to MySQL is working, and the select command works fine too.

My code goes as follows:

```py
import mysql.connector
datenbank=mysql.connector.connect(
    user="********",
    password="*********",
    host="*********"
    )

cursor=datenbank.cursor()
print("test")
cursor.execute("USE Fill_in_the_blanks_game")
cursor.execute("INSERT active_rooms VALUES (5, 6574, 'jannik')")
cursor.fetchall
print("test")
```

Comment: What do you expect to return from cursor.fetchall()? In contrast to SELECT statements, an INSERT statement does not return a result set.

Answer (score 0):

Any modification you made to your data will only be visible from that session until you commit it:

```
datenbank.commit()
```